# Entity Comparison for Top Values and Lowest Values Query Report

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to make a comparison to a specific university, for example, Stetson University. I have already got a query that will show me the 10 highest and lowest schools for loan debt at a certain percent degree completion. I just need to compare that specific college in the report with the 10 highest and lowest schools at a certain percent degree completion.

- 10 highest and lowest schools for loan debt at 10% degree completion
- 10 highest and lowest schools for loan debt at 25% degree completion
- 10 highest and lowest schools for loan debt at 75% degree completion
- 10 highest and lowest schools for loan debt at 90% degree completion

Here is the query I ran previously for the 90 percentile:

```
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID, INSTNM, CUML_DEBT_P90 FROM MERGED2013_DebtOnly WHERE CUML_DEBT_P90 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2)) DESC 

SELECT TOP 10 UNITID, INSTNM, CUML_DEBT_P90 FROM MERGED2013_DebtOnly WHERE CUML_DEBT_P90 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2)) ASC
```

Here are the data types:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MERGED2013_DebtOnly](
[UNITID] [float] NULL,
[INSTNM] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[CUML_DEBT_N] [float] NULL,
[CUML_DEBT_P90] [float] NULL,
[CUML_DEBT_P75] [float] NULL,
[CUML_DEBT_P25] [float] NULL,
[CUML_DEBT_P10] [float] NULL,
```

**Desired Results Image**:

[image: Desired Results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this. It returns your school and it's places in all orders:

```
;WITH cte as (
    SELECT UNITID, INSTNM, CUML_DEBT_N, C150_4_POOLED_SUPP
        , CUML_DEBT_P10_ASC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P10 ASC)
        , CUML_DEBT_P10_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P10 DESC)
        , CUML_DEBT_P25_ASC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P25 ASC)
        , CUML_DEBT_P25_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P25 DESC)
        , CUML_DEBT_P75_ASC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P75 ASC)
        , CUML_DEBT_P75_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P75 ASC)
        , CUML_DEBT_P90_ASC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P90 ASC)
        , CUML_DEBT_P90_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P90 DESC)
    FROM    [dbo].[MERGED2013_DebtOnly])
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE INSTNM = 'Stetson University';
```

BTW review your scripts you there is a mess with ASC/DESC

Comment: How would you compare it in a list of the 10 highest and lowest? I had to remake the query because of null values. 

SELECT TOP 10 UNITID, INSTNM, CUML_DEBT_P90 FROM MERGED2013_DebtOnly WHERE CUML_DEBT_P90 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2)) DESC

Comment: I do not know your data. If you have nulls you have to handle them.

Comment: I'm not getting nulls anymore with the query commented. I just need to compare them in a list of colleges; your query does return the results that I need; however, only showing 'stetson university.' I just need to compare the college in a list of top 10 in a certain percentile.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. Can you provide samples of desired output?

Comment: I edited my post to make to update it; here is the link to desired results https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEtNV.png. The school 'Stetson University' should be compared to these schools when the query is run.

Comment: If that is what you want, then just do your TOP 10 query and use "UNION" with a school you want to compare. I think that is not the best way. It does not show the whole picture, but it is up to you.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped and I learned something along the way.